# What is the difference between token identifier WORD and NAME?

Tags: shell, posix, terminology

In POSIX 7, the shell grammar (Section 2.10 in XCU)  mentions several token identifiers. I am confused about two: WORD and NAME. What are their differences?

For example, is a command's option WORD or NAME? How about a command's non-optional argument?

Answer (score 3):

All of the uppercase names in this section refer to (possibly machine-compilable) `lex` descriptions of the grammar (starting in [2.10. Shell Grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10)).  The feature asked about is clarified in item 5:

> [ **`NAME`** in **`for`**]

When the **`TOKEN`** meets the requirements for a name (see [XBD Name](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_231) ), the token identifier **`NAME`** shall result. Otherwise, the token **`WORD`** shall be returned.

That is (referring to [3.231 Name](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_231)), a **`NAME`** is a certain type of **`WORD`**:

> In the shell command language, a *word* consisting solely of underscores, digits, and alphabetics from the portable character set. The first character of a *name* is not a digit.

Not all words are names: a decimal integer is a word, but not a name.

Regarding the grammar, these lines tell `yacc` what symbolic constants (via `#define`) `lex` might return:

```
%token  WORD
%token  ASSIGNMENT_WORD
%token  NAME
%token  NEWLINE
%token  IO_NUMBER
```

while the `yacc` grammar (rules) begins with

```
%start  complete_command
```

You may notice occurrences of `WORD` and `NAME` in the grammar.  `yacc` expects `lex` to return those symbolic constants at those points.  Conventionally, uppercase names are used for this purpose, with other names being just the rules within the `yacc` grammar.

When interpreting a command, the shell interpreter only cares about the first WORD, which it expects to be a NAME.  It passes the other WORDs to the command as parameters, and the command has to decide what those mean.  The `yacc` grammar is vague in this area, but note the reference to "7a". There is no labeled item for that in the written standard, but it devolves off to *[2.9.1 Simple Commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01)* corresponding to this clump in the grammar:

```
simple_command   : cmd_prefix cmd_word cmd_suffix
                 | cmd_prefix cmd_word
                 | cmd_prefix
                 | cmd_name cmd_suffix
                 | cmd_name
```

(as an exercise, someone might try completing the grammar and making it actually *match* the standard with respect to terminology).

Comment: Thanks. I am more wondering what the tokens with "WORD" and "NAME" identifiers are used for? more about their meanings than their syntax.

Comment: For example, is a command's option WORD or NAME? How about a command's non-optional argument?

Answer (score 0):

Word in the command line processing aspect is what is usually understood as a word in many languages: some group of characters limited (mostly) by spaces.

Technically, a group of characters separated by metacharacters (characters that, when unquoted, separates words).

The first step from [a very clear description of command line processing](http://helios.cs.ifmo.ru/~ad/Documentation/Bash_Shell/bash3-CHP-7-SECT-3.html):

1. Splits the command into tokens that are separated by the fixed set of metacharacters: SPACE, TAB, NEWLINE, ;, (, ), <, >, |, and &. Types of tokens include words, keywords, I/O redirectors, and semicolons.

**After** the line has been divided into **Words** (or tokens), tokens are identified using syntax rules and labeled acordingly.

---

Name is just a label used to identify something: a command name, a variable name, a parameter name, a builtin name, etc.