# REOPEN: Perform arithmetic expansion inside parameter expansion?

Tags: bash

Please reopen. This is not a duplicate, because here I am asking why it doesn't work, not just for workaround.

---

Bash manual says that

> tilde expansion, **parameter and variable expansion**, **arithmetic expansion**, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion)

If I understand http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/270324/674 correctly,  "left-to-right" means that "brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution" have the same priority.

So is it possible to use arithmetic expansion inside parameter expansion? (i.e. one level recursion)

If no, why can't arithmetic expansion work inside parameter expansion, given that "tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion)"?

If yes, how?

For example,

```
$ set hello world
$ echo $2
world
$ echo ${$((1+1))}
bash: ${$((1+1))}: bad substitution
```

I hope to

- first expand `$((1+1))` in `${$((1+1))}` to `2`. and
- then `${2}` to `world`.

Thanks.

Comment: Because that's not left-to-right.  What you're hoping for is not left-to-right.  The documentation says expansion is done left-to-right.  You want something else, I don't know what to call it; maybe "from-inside-to-outside" parsing?  Please read the documentation *and clear the English words in it* like "left-to-right" so you can answer your own questions.  (This question *contains* its own answer.)

Comment: What the manual tries to say is: parameter expansion is done before arithmetic expansion, so it works the other way around: `set 6 7; echo $(($1*$2))` will work as expected.

Comment: @phi. Where does the manual say that  parameter expansion is done before arithmetic expansion?

Comment: The whole sentence of your citation is: "*The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and pathname expansion.*

Comment: @Philippos you misunderstood the meaning of "left-to-right" https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/270324/674. "brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution" have the same priority.

Comment: @Tim they don't (and can't) have the same priority. Parameter expansion is done before arithmetic expansion, so `$(( 1 + ${a:-5} ))` will work but `${ $((1 + 1)) }` won't. To solve your requirement you would need `set 4 5; b=$((1+1)); echo ${!b}`

Comment: Roaima is right. The order of evaluations is what is quoted by Philippos. As for "left-to-right", it does not specify the respective order of the different kinds of expansions, it specifies the evaluation order for **each** kind of expansion. Left-to-right means that `${undefined:=foo}${undefined}` evaluates to `foofoo` whereas it would evaluate to `foo` if the evaluation was right-to-left. Likewise, left-to-right means that in `$(cmd1)$(cmd2)`, `cmd1` is executed before `cmd2`.

Comment: Just to add more confusion in Tim's head, `${@:$((1+1)):1}` would work though ;-) Hint: `${@:1+1:1}` would work too.

Answer (score 3):

You need either `eval` or indirection for this:

```
eval echo \${$((1+1))}
index=$((1+1))
echo ${!index}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand the two ways you mentioned. Why can't arithmetic expansion work inside parameter expansion, given that "tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion)"?

Comment: @Tim, because that *wouldn't be left-to-right.*