# Bash script copy file to user's (wildcard) home dir

Tags: shell-script, wildcards, cp, tilde

I need to copy `/root/nbu/file1.sh` to every user's home directory if user's id is even number.

Trying to execute following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /etc/passwd | while read LINE
do
    username=$(awk -v var="$LINE" -F: '{
        if ($3 % 2 == 0)
           print $1
        }')
    cp /root/nbu/file1.sh ~"$username"
done
```

And it does nothing. If I echo `cp /root/nbu/file1.sh ~"$username"` command and execute it directly in the script, it works.

I guess the problem is that `~` gets expanded in the bash script, but can't figure out how to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just a note, ~ is tilde, and $username is a variable; there are no "wildcards" present here. ... Unless [one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/135943/wildcard) shows up to answer :)

Comment: Relating only: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270274/how-to-understand-the-order-between-expansions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem on the ball so I won't spoon-feed you a script, but here are some pointers:

1. You're using `awk` incorrectly. Try this instead:

   ```
   awk -F: -v uid_min=${UID_MIN:-1000} '$3%2==0 && $3>uid_min && $3!=65534{print $6}' /etc/passwd
   ```
2. There's no need for `cat`.
3. Use your `awk` output as the input to your `read` loop, ie. `while read USER_HOME_DIR ; do ... ; done < $(awk...)`. Understand that this will mean that only one `awk` process needs to be spawned, while your original script spawns a separate `awk` process for each line, so this is much more efficient.
4. Add a check in your `awk` program to limit it to UID's above 1000, or you will inadvertently perform your copy for many system users.
5. Note that in #1 above, I changed your `$1` to `$6` in order to pull the user's home directory instead of the user's name.
6. I just noticed on my debian machine that there exists a 'nobody' user with UID 65534, so you may need to account for that. I modified the `awk` statement in #1 accordingly.
7. As per user Jeff Schaller's comment, I've modified the `awk` program to account for a custom minimum UID. The form `${UID_MIN:-1000}` means set the value as 1000 if it would otherwise be null or unset.

Comment: The Q isn't tagged linux, but if that's the scope, you might use `UID_MIN` rather than hard-coding 1000 in case the local sysadmin adjusted it.

Comment: @JeffSchaller - Thanks. incorporated into the answer.

Comment: I should have clarified -- UID_MIN isn't globally set; it's a parameter in /etc/login.defs; sorry!

Comment: Well, at least it was an opportunity teach the shell idiom `${FOO:-default}`. At this point, I'll leave it in for that reason, and won't further change the answer, on the basis that the person running the script or one-liner will be a sysadmin who will know what the UID_MIN value is.

Answer (score 7):

The tilde expansion doesn't work if the username part is quoted:

```
$ echo ~root ~"root"
/root ~root
```

(and it happens before variable expansion anyway.)

But since you're already reading `passwd` in the shell, why not just do it the full way:

```
#!/bin/bash
getent passwd | while IFS=: read -r user pass uid gid gecos home shell; do 
    if (( uid % 2 == 0 )); then
        echo "uid $uid of user '$user' is even and their home is '$home'";
    fi; 
done
```

If your system has `getent`, it's probably better to use it, rather than `/etc/passwd` directly.

On the other hand, since you don't really seem to need the username for anything, you could just have your `awk` script output the *directory* (`$6`) instead.

Answer (score 6):

That's because [tilde expansion happens before variable expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions):

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and filename expansion.

`echo`ing the result *looks* correct, and works if you re-evaluate it, but for a script, you'll need to do it differently. Perhaps:

```
# ...
homedir=$(getent passwd "$username" | cut -d: -f6)
cp /root/nbu/file1.sh "$homedir"
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I can do it in a one-liner. Check this out:

```
eval $(awk -v source="/root/nbu/file1.sh" -v uid_min=${UID_MIN:-1000} -F: '$3%2==0 && $3>uid_min && $3!=65534{printf "cp %s %s ;", source, $6 }' /etc/passwd)
```

For readability:

```
eval $( 
  awk \
    -v source="/root/nbu/file1.sh" \
    -v uid_min=${UID_MIN:-1000} \
    -F: '
      $3%2==0 && $3>uid_min && $3!=65534 {
         printf "cp %s %s ;", source, $6 
      }
    ' /etc/passwd 
  )
```

Comment: I would use `source <( awk '...' )` instead of eval.