# Passing a Directory to cd

Tags: cd-command, fzf

I have a function, which I would hope would get me a fuzzy search on the latest directories I have been looking at and save me time, a simple 1 liner:

```bsh
dirs | sed 'y/ /\n/' | fzf | xargs cd
```

2 hours later I can't figure out what's wrong ) :

I keep getting errors like:

```
/usr/bin/cd: line 4: cd: ~/Downloads/demo: No such file or directory
```

Even when the directory does exist, no matter what I do. What is up with cd, why doesn't this work?

**Thanks for Comment: More Info**
I've tried a few other ways, such as writing a function:

```
fdr() {
     local dir
     dir=`dirs | sed 'y/ /\n/' | fzf`
     cd $dir
}
```

Even though `dir` has the correct value, I get the same error as seen above.

**My Final Function**

Thanks for the help, sub shells were doing my head in, here is my final answer, bit hackey, but what isn't these days.

```bsh
fdr() {
  local dir
  myusernmae=`whoami`
  dir=`dirs | sed 'y/ /\n/' | sed "s/~/\/Users\/$myusernmae/g" | fzf +m`
  cd "$dir"
}
```

Comment: Components in a pipeline execute in subshells, except for certain shells (e.g. ksh). Consider trying command substitution (`"$( <pipeline> )"`).

Comment: Also, `~/Downloads/demo` is expanded *by the shell* not by the `cd` command.

Comment: Check it out! Pretty awful huh? haha does the job. I pity the fool who copies my `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Actually I fixed it now, bothered me too much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three issues here:

1. The directory pathname is given to `cd` as the literal string `~/Downloads/demo` even though the correct path may be something like `/Users/snickers/Download/demo`.

   Usually when you type `cd ~/Downloads/demo` on the command line, the shell will expand the tilde to the path of your home directory before running the `cd` command.  This does not happen here because tilde expansion happens before variable expansion (see "[How to understand the order between expansions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270274/how-to-understand-the-order-between-expansions)").

   Assuming that you're using the `bash` shell, using `dirs -l` may bypass this issue by letting `dirs` output the full path.
2. `cd` is a shell built-in command.  On your macOS machine, it is also available as the external command `/usr/bin/cd`, which is why you're not getting a "command not found" error like many other Unix user would get when using `cd` with `xargs`.  However, an external `cd` command can never change the directory for the current shell.  This is described in "[Why is cd not a program?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38808/why-is-cd-not-a-program)" and "[where is `cd` located?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116955/where-is-cd-located)" and in similar questions.  Your shell function variation bypasses this issue since its using your shell's built-in `cd` command.
3. The last issue, which is a variant of the 2nd issue and which really doesn't come into play because of the other issues, is that the `cd` command, when executed by `xargs`, is not only an external command that can't change the working directory for the calling shell, but the command that is calling it is `xargs`, which in turn is running in a sub-shell as a stage of your pipeline.  Changing the shell in a sub-shell won't change it in the parent shell.

You should be able to use

```bash
fdr () {
   cd "$( dirs -l -p | fzf )"
}
```

where `dirs -l -p` outputs one directory from the directory stack in `bash` per line, with tildes expanded.  This assumes that you don't have directories on the stack with embedded newlines in their names, but *will* support directories with spaces (which your own function does not do, partly because of the `sed` transformations and partly because of not quoting the expansion of `$dir`).